# Electron updater keeps new updates at user level

Tags: electron, electron-builder, electron-updater

I install my electron app (msi build for Windows) with the following script:

`msiexec /i "https://URL_TO_MY_APP_Messenger.msi" MSIINSTALLPERUSER=""`

and it was installed under *C:\Program Files\Messenger*, which is expected since I want the app at system level

But As I can see I have another folder at
*C:\Users\Ismoil\AppData\Local\messenger-updater* looks like that's where electron updater keeps updates with some files in that folder

- installer.exe
- pending/Messenger-some-version-number.exe
- pending/update-info.json

and once the app is updated, I end up seeing 2 apps on my Desktop screen bcs the new updated install is located at user level under
*C:\Users\Ismoil\AppData\Local\Programs\Messenger*

how can I resolve it?

Ideally, I want to control the update folder depending on the MSIINSTALLPERUSER="" (system level) MSIINSTALLPERUSER="1" (user level)

If it is not possible, I want to keep my app only under system level, but looks like **electron-updater** keeps updates only at user level

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Looks like auto-updater doesn't support MSI builds, I think that's the reason why we usually see 2 versions of Messenger in Windows.
In our case, auto-updater was working through NSIS `.exe` installations so far.
Partners install the `msi` build using the script and since auto-updater doesn't support `msi`, it was just downloading and installing `.exe` version of the app (at USER level) that creates a duplicate if `msi` was initially installed at SYSTEM level

Unfortunately, as of 2024 `electron-updater` stil has no support for auto-updates for MSI, it only supports NSIS (.exe)
Since **it is not possible to combine MSI and exe for auto updates to be at SYSTEM level**, we're going to terminate the support for MSI and keep only NSIS (that supports SYSTEM level only auto-updates)

```json
"nsis": {
  "deleteAppDataOnUninstall": true,
  "perMachine": true // SYSTEM level
},
```

related Github issue: https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-builder/issues/3322